# Mod-Rewrite: only in specific directory and before the other directories

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

To be a bit more concrete:
I want a Link that looks like

```
domain.com/onlyinthisdir/en/something/ OR
domain.com/onlyinthisdir/en/something/some/thing/
```

but Mod rewrite makes it to

```
domain.com/onlyinthisdir/something/?lang=en
domain.com/onlyinthisdir/something/some/thing/?lang=en
```

Not with a user-redirection, but that it only happens internally.

My first try was that. But it's only working with the "onlyinthisdir" dir, but not the other below

```
RewriteRule ^onlyinthisdir/([^/]*)/$ /onlyinthisdir/?lang=$1 [L]
```

I'm not even sure if this really works. Is there a better option to detect the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^onlyinthisdir/([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /onlyinthisdir/$2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: that's quite brilliant!